# iOS tab bar object holder

Tags: ios5, tabs

I am new to Obj-C so I will be happy for any best practice idea or something.
I have a table view with some objects. When any object is selected I would like to open an object detail view with tabs. These tabs divide the object properties to some logical groups.
But it still describe one object and I would like the user has an experience when creating the new object he can switch between tabs and change the values without any saving data until the save button (common for all tabs in navigation bar) was clicked.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking for. I think you can use UINavigationController to lead the user to the detail screen, in the detail screen use UITableView to display your object detail. If you want to group them, you can set the tableView style to Grouped.

If you are asking for something else, please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, yes i am trying to do what you have dscribed but instead of grouped table view i would like to use tabs. So e.g. object of class Employee could be shown in TabBar controller and tabs would be (profile, contract, other) - All of these tabs would include some fields of the Employee class. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you considered UIToolBar? It can do what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To be idiomatic with the iOS experience, displaying the Tab Bar should be a modal dialog with a "Done" button then.

Create a UINavigationController and place the UITTabBarController as the root controller of it, then in the navigation bar of the root controller place 'Done' button.

Note that you must keep a temporary model of whatever you are editing in memory (I would suggest subclassing UINavigationController, adding a property for the object and passing a pointer to the object to all of the tab controllers), since the views containing the changed data can be deallocated at any time when they are not displayed to save memory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I caught your point. That is exectly what I need - some kind of Tabbar with 3 tabs inside one Navigation controller. I am using iOS 5 and storyboarding but I cannot attach tabbar inside the navigation (only opposite way). Do I have to do it by code? Would it be working? thanks